# Java Tableau Charting solution required

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, extjs, tableau-api

We are trying to plot a tree like structure in tableau. Java may also be used. The problem is that there are multiple trees and the depth of the tree is arbitrary. In the following context I would like to know the following:-

1> How to plot the tree in node like structure and possible algorithm for the generation of the co-ordinates to be used as plotting by tableau.

2> Is it possible to carry out the same functionality of tableau using other charting solutions like java,js,or extjs.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: JavaScript !== Java

Comment: Know that but am looking at possible solution in the fields in java and JavaScript and UI technology.